# Why is subprocess showing partial stdout?

Tags: python, subprocess

Why is subprocess not displaying full output of the command?

My command output is in below format:

```
    DATABASE_NAME: TSMDB1
TOT_FILE_SYSTEM_MB: 1536000
USED_DB_SPACE_MB: 1301095
  FREE_SPACE_MB: 213555
    TOTAL_PAGES: 62582620
   USABLE_PAGES: 62574860
     USED_PAGES: 61566280
     FREE_PAGES: 1008580
 BUFF_HIT_RATIO: 92.6
 TOTAL_BUFF_REQ: 1233581268360
  SORT_OVERFLOW: 0
  PKG_HIT_RATIO: 98.2
     LAST_REORG: 2020-04-26 14:33:55.000000
 FULL_DEV_CLASS: LTO4_CLASS1
NUM_BACKUP_INCR: 0
LAST_BACKUP_DATE: 2020-04-27 07:00:11.000000
PHYSICAL_VOLUMES: 10
NUM_BACKUP_STREAMS: 3
COMPRESS_DB_BACKUPS: No
PROTECT_MASTER_KEY: No
```

With subprocess

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = proc.communicate()
```

I only get part of the output similar to below.

```
     TSMDB1
     1536000
     1301095
     213555
     62582620
     62574860
     62574860
     1008580
     92.6
     1233581268360
     0
     98.2
     2020-04-26 14:33:55.000000
     LTO4_CLASS1
     0
     2020-04-27  07:00:11.000000
     10
     3
     No
     No
```

I am trying to read it as a string, But still do not understand why the first part of the command is missing? I am running this on RHEL V7 server with Python 2.7.

Comment: Some commands detect if their standard output is a terminal or not, and alter their output accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Chepner for the input, It is possible. I will look into the command..

Answer (score 0):

chepner suggestion is correct. the command is not giving complete output..